# Cite not appearing when I am using \cite command also not able to format the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I was trying to use the bibliography command, and the following code which I was using is uploaded below, I am not able to see the cite and it is showing a question mark in the Latex output, also I was trying to change the format to ams and it is not showing any output, can anyone please suggest what error can be??

```
\subsection{bibliography}

This part was taken from the following paper: \cite{paper name}
 
\bibliographystyle{ams}
 
\bibliography{ref}
```

[image: I have added the image for the output here, please check]

Comment: what you show is the expected output until you generate the bibliography by running bibtex

Comment: in most styles `\bibliography` will already generate the  `\section{..}` heading so you probably should not have the first part of the code that you show, it will not error, but it will give you two bibliography sections.

Comment: texlive does not have an `ams.bib` bibliography style, is that a local file that you have or a typo (which would give an error when you run bibtex)

Comment: There is a  .bib file named ref which I was trying to run, so I downloaded it, My goal is first to run the.bib folder which is in IEEE format and then convert it into different format

Comment: I did not ask about `ref` but about the specified `\bibliographystyle` which references `ams.bib` which is not a standard style, so the expectation would be you get an error from bibtex and no bibliography generated, which would match your question

Comment: I see that now, so I should probably change this to a format that does exist and which is a standard style, to get the results!!

Comment: don't ignore error messages  if bibtex reports that it did not generate a bibliography, latex will not show one. But also please always provide a complete small test document here not a fragment

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

This part was taken from the following paper: \cite{article-minimal}
 
\bibliographystyle{ams}
 
\bibliography{xampl}


\end{document}
```

(using a sample bib file that is in texlive) produces

[image]

which is the expected output. Note that you show a different form with a space before `:` and ?? rather than [?] but as you have provided no example that is not reproducible.

If after running pdflatex once you run bibtex to generate the bibliography, then  you get:

```
$ bibtex bb812
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2021)
The top-level auxiliary file: bb812.aux
I couldn't open style file ams.bst
---line 3 of file bb812.aux
 : \bibstyle{ams
 :              }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file bb812.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
```

and no bibliography generated as the `\bibliographystyle` references an unknown style. Changing to the  `plain` style:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

This part was taken from the following paper: \cite{article-minimal}
 
\bibliographystyle{plain}
 
\bibliography{xampl}


\end{document}
```

running pdflatex again, then bibtex, the terminal shows:

```
$ bibtex bb812
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2021)
The top-level auxiliary file: bb812.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: xampl.bib
```

and running pdflatex again *twice* to resolve the cross references  produces

[image]